# TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date in Saleor

Tags: python-3.x, saleor

```
saleor/core/models.py", line 76, in is_visible
    or self.publication_date <= datetime.date.today()
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

to fix this problem, but may be this is because of timezone.
```

currently this error was happening in saloer/core/models.py

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.